# Dwb local planner or standard navigation stack?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-kinetic, obstacle-avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the D. Lu's [github page](https://github.com/locusrobotics/robot_navigation/tree/master/dwb_local_planner) and his [video conference](https://vimeo.com/236487972), Dwb local planner seems to be a good alternative to the standard navigation implementation.
Yet I wonder if anyone has tried it and if it is easier to use than the standard approach.

Currently, I am a little confused since M. Lu advises me to check the standard [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation)

https://answers.ros.org/question/286987/implement-obstacle-avoidance-methods-and-local-navigation-move_base/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289105/dwb-local-planner-or-standard-navigation-stack-?/) by [sustainable](https://answers.ros.org/users/34385/sustainable/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2018-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are both viable alternatives. However, if you are just becoming familiar with ROS Navigation, I would recommend starting with the standard turtlebot configuration linked in the other answer before trying to get the new planner working.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sustainable](https://answers.ros.org/users/34385/sustainable/) on 2018-04-20**:
Ok, I will follow your advice.